# YouTube blocked video for display on website

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

A YouTube video is not being played due to copyright issue and gives a message as follows:

> This video contains content from *somebody*, who has blocked it from display on this website or application.
> Watch on YouTube.

Here is the [JSfiddle for two videos](https://jsfiddle.net/wjsmahbq/1/), where one video is being played but the other is not:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <iframe allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UPLNXZQdGxo?autoplay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <br />
  <iframe allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6jiNS_4CEug?autoplay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to support playing such videos?

Comment: Where are you from? In Italy they work

Comment: I'm from India.

Comment: Surprisingly, it is also being played for me!

Comment: Ok, I mean the jsfiddle you sent works for me.

Comment: I think you can’t do anything to make it work: some YouTube videos that have music or other Content ID material cannot be embedded. I can say that for experience, but unfortunately I haven’t found any official documentation about the topic yet.

Comment: Please, could you check if there is a section called “music in this video” in the descriptions of the videos? Also take a look at https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7680188

Comment: As a workaround, you could download the video with https://youtube-dl.org/ and host it yourself. Depending on your jurisdiction you might be breaking copyright laws by doing this, however.

Comment: I think there is no legal solution to this. Check this link "Block videos in specific territories" (https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9693128?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

### Video isn't available in my country/region

> Some YouTube videos may not
> be available in your country/region for the following reasons:
>
> Video owners have chosen to make their content available only to
> certain countries/regions (usually due to licensing rights) YouTube
> may block specific content to comply with local laws

-- [Youtube](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/92571)

Basically this means that the video isn't playable in your region. While it may become available in the future, currently you cannot do anything about that.

For future reference, this [online tool](https://unblockvideos.com/youtube-video-restriction-checker) checks if a video is available in your region.

Hope this answered your question!

Answer (score 0):

the link you provided works for me. (I'm in Germany)
I think it is best to test your solution with different localization since I'm guessing YouTube is blocking it for you specifically for you. There might be plenty of reasons besides localization like age restriction etc.

Uploading Video to a different platform might help